# Getting requests for suspicious php files

Tags: php, web-server, web-crawler

I am getting weird GET requests on my (non php supporting) web server for some curious looking php files. Was just wondering whether these are harmless requests of certain browser tools or attempts from a crawler to find flaws / misconfigurations in php web servers. Got me a little worried. And in case it is an attempt to find vulnerabilities, what actions would you recommend I take.

A part of the log is in the screenshot. (Note: the IP-Address from which the requests have been sent is the local IP of a reverse proxy in my server network)

```
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52954 [GET] /x.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52962 [GET] /wso.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52964 [GET] /srx.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52968 [GET] /1337.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52970 [GET] /xx.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52972 [GET] /XxX.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52978 [GET] /leaf.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52986 [GET] /leafmailer2.8.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52988 [GET] /bb.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:52992 [GET] /m.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:49 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53006 [GET] /Lux.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:50 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53010 [GET] /haxor.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:50 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53014 [GET] /shell.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:50 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53016 [GET] /qindex.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:50 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53018 [GET] /alex.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:50 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53024 [GET] /1.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:50 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53026 [GET] /wp2.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:50 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53030 [GET] /wp.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:50 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53032 [GET] /stindex.php
[3/2/2022, 7:04:50 PM] ::ffff:172.19.0.4:53036 [GET] /lf.php
```

[Log of web server requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvpRP.png)

Comment: Welcome to the internet. Get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is suspicious activity, but as Gerald commented, this is both normal and expected for a webserver, a remote server is performing multiple HTTP GET requests to look for well known PHP files such as word press etc. your server will return 404 to the attacker or 200 if such a file exists, if such a file does exist as the one this script is looking for then further action could be taken based on known vulnerabilities of those files - there are several methods for dealing with bots, web crawlers and phishing, some methods are client/sever centric and some are network related